# Why am I getting this huge numbers in C?

Tags: c, arrays, windows, eof

I'm trying to teach myself C using Kernighan's book and I'm supposed to make a graph that indicates how many letters there are in each word. I haven't got to the "plotting" part as I'm getting really weird and enormous numbers at the output. Right now I'm just trying to have the value of the first and second elements of the array "arreglo" printed.

The code is the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define ARRAY_SIZE 100

/*#define AUX 0
#define AUX2 0*/

main()
{
    int s,j,noletra,i,arreglo[ARRAY_SIZE],otros, nopalabra, c;
    int a;
nopalabra=1;

    while((c=getchar())!=EOF)
{
        if(c==' '||c=='\t'||c=='\n')
               ++nopalabra;
        else
               ++arreglo[nopalabra];
        }
        printf("%d",arreglo[1],arreglo[2]);

}
```

The reason I'm trying to know the value in the second element in the array is that the first element has the correct value. The code is supposed to add 1 to the array index which is the number of words each time a space, tab or \n is typed and to add 1 to the array element whenever something different than the previously mentioned characters is typed (Letters). Right now it´s supposed to print correctly the number of the letters of two words, the first element is correctly printed but the second is a huge number, the output is:

```
    alan amaury
^Z
4 8257542
--------------------------------
Process exited after 7.773 seconds with return value 9
Press any key to continue . . .
```

The output is supposed to be 4 7. I'm using a compiler in windows so EOF should be Ctrl+Z

Any help that I could get from you will be appreciated :)

Comment: You didn't initialize `arreglo` before using it.

Comment: It is a good habit to initialize all variables when you define them.

Comment: Aside: please remember that the array should be indexed from `0` to `ARRAY_SIZE - 1`.

Comment: The indentation on this code is a wreck. That helps communicate not only flow, but *intent*, and helps avoid ugly, hard to see bugs.

Comment: Have you included the same version of your code that generated that output? There is no way the included code could print out two numbers.

Comment: @ChrisTurner why not? There is a `while` loop and no newline output.

Comment: @ChrisTurner on consideration, you are right - there is no space printed to output.

Comment: regarding: `main()`   The compiler will output a warning message about this line.  This can be fixed by using: `int main( void )`

Comment: regarding: `if(c==' '||c=='\t'||c=='\n')`  probably also want to check for `,` `.` `;` and `:`.   Suggest examining the contents of the header file: `ctype.h` for further information and some predefined macros.

Comment: @WeatherVane hard to tell with the poor formatting, but the `printf` is outside the `while` loop

Answer (score 6):

At least these problems.

1. `int arreglo[ARRAY_SIZE];` is not initialized before its elements are incremented.  This is the mostly likely cause of  "Why am I getting this huge numbers"  [@ikegami](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48306310/2410359)

   ```
    // int arreglo[ARRAY_SIZE];
    // replace with 
    int arreglo[ARRAY_SIZE] = { 0 };
   ```
2. Code can access out of array bounds as `nopalabra` is not confined to 0 to 99.

   ```
   #define ARRAY_SIZE 100
   int arreglo[ARRAY_SIZE];
   ++arreglo[nopalabra];  // No access protection
   ```
3. `printf("%d",arreglo[1],arreglo[2]);` only prints `arreglo[1]`
4. Logic flow is incorrect to "make a graph that indicates how many letters there are in each word."
5. `main()` return type not coded.

---

Some pseudo-code as an alternative

```
int main(void) {
  set all arreglo[] to 0
  int nopalabra = 0;
  part_of_word = false;  // Keep track of word state
  loop forever {
    get a character into c
    if c is a separator or EOF
      if (part_of_word) {
        arreglo[nopalabra]++;
        part_of_word = false;
      nopalabra = 0;
      if (c == EOF) break loop
    } else {
      nopalabra++;
      part_of_word = true;
    }
  }

  print out results
}
```

Answer (score 1):

On the side:
Your call to `printf()` has more parameters than covered by the format string.
So you should clean up your code to something similar to

```
printf("%d %d\n", arreglo[1], arreglo[2]);
```

Concerning the strange output:
A way of getting surprising values is using non-initialised variables.
In your case the lack of initialisation affects the array `arreglo`.
Make sure to initialise it, so that all counting starts on a meaningful value.

Another way of getting seemingly very high values is printing several numbers next to each other, without separating white space in between.
So the " " and the "\n" in the format string I proposed are quite relevant.

Comment: @chux Thanks, I was baited into the trap of lazyness by a seven-figure rep.... ;-)

Comment: Ok, my code works now. I initialized the array and all variables. I also made sure the array was indexed from 1 to ARRAY_SIZE-1. I indexed the array from 1 because I assumed there had already been a word typed as I usually don´t start typing by using a space, I must work in a more robust version however.

Comment: I would like to post the code with the corrections added to get feedback from you but there is a limit. Does anybody know how to do so without stackoverflow assuming I'm answering my own question?

Comment: It is OK to answer your own question. It might even get you a badge. You can show your final solution for the benefit of others. If none of the existing answers was even close you can accept your own answer. If you basically use one of the answers and have just fine-tuned it a little, you can consider accepting that answer instead of your own.

Answer (score 1):

First, try the solution answered before, changing the printf() call.

If there is still a problem try:

```
     printf("%d %d \n",arreglo[1],arreglo[2]);
```

Just before the while loop, to see if the "arreglo" array is initialize to 0's or just random values.

Answer (score 0):

the question is: "Why am I getting this huge numbers in C?"

the answer is: you have not assigned anything to arreglo array, and since you have not initialized it, you got some random values that have been there in memory. Trust me on this, I have run your code in debugger, which I also highly recommend a a standard practice while lerning to program.

Also, this is a common mistake where the format specifier is not written:
printf("%d",arreglo[1],arreglo[2]);

See if using printf("%d","%d",arreglo[1],arreglo[2]) solves your problem.

By the way, K&R book is very old, and written at the time where there have been no other C books. There are better ways to learn C.